# Angular1 : not able to pass the param to the back end

Tags: java, angularjs

I am working with angular1 on java-spring MVC framework. I have a **backend java service** as :

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/layout/guess/{id}/{maxColumns}/{origin}", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public ResponseEntity<?> guessLayout( @PathVariable( "id" ) long id,
        @PathVariable( "maxColumns" ) int maxColumns,
        @RequestParam( value = "delimeter", required = true)  String delimiter,
        @PathVariable( "luckyOrigin" ) String origin )
{
    try
    {
        //do something with delimiter
     }
 }
```

Now **from frontend javascript controller/service** I am calling the above service as (inside a function):

```
return $http.post( 'submenu/layout/guess/' + id + '/' + maxColumns  + "/" + origin,
            delimiter)
            .then(
                function( response )
                {
                    return response.data;
                },
                function( errResponse )
                {
                    console.error( 'Error while guessFieldLayout' );
                    return $q.reject( errResponse );
                }
            );
```

And always getting **an error** as :

```
Required String parameter 'delimeter' is not present
```

**I can not use the "delimiter" as part of the URL.** Any insight on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I believe Request Parameters look something like this: http://example.com/page?parameter=value  try adding ?delimeter=delimeter to your url

Comment: ^^^ THIS... you are sending as post body but expecting it in url as param. you can create a POJO Delimeter and then use @RequestBody for that type in the method signature. or pull the delimeter from the httprequest.